# Can a Non-EU citizen who worked in a EU country with specific work permit have the right to apply to ECHR for workplace discrimination?

Tags: employment, european-union, discrimination, human-rights, ireland

I am a citizen of Turkey, not of the EU. I worked in Ireland with a Critical Skills Employment Permit.

I sued my employer for Workplace Discrimination. I decided that the case was not dealt with properly. After I exhaust all the internal procedures, I am planning to apply to European Court of Human Rights - ECHR. But I read that "People can go to ECHR only against the countries of their own".

Is this correct? Do I have the right to go to the ECHR?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [pamphlet](https://www.echr.coe.int/Documents/Questions_Answers_ENG.pdf) (see page 5), no, you do not need to be a citizen of the EU country.

> **What are the conditions relating to me personally?**
>
> You do not need to be a national of one of the States bound
> by the Convention. The violation you are complaining of must
> simply have been committed by one of those States against
> a person within its “jurisdiction”, which usually means on its
> territory

Comment: Which also means that the OP needs to have a case against the state, not the employer (unless they are the same thing).  Perhaps they were thinking about the European Court of Justice?